# parallel running of jobs in unix

Tags: unix, loops, parallel-processing

I have following jobs (just as example) to run in unix (bash shell) cluster computers:

```
### job1
mkdir file01
cp *.map  flex01
date > out
cd ..

### job2
mkdir file02
cp *.map  flex02
date > out
cd ..

### job3
mkdir file03
cp *.map  flex03
date > out
cd ..

### job4
mkdir file04
cp *.map  flex04
date > out
cd ..
```

If I submit these jobs, we do one by one. But I want to run them in parallel means that job1 to job4 running at the same time at the background.

How can I do it ? Sorry for the simple question, I am new to unix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cd` commands don't seem to be a good idea; you don't `cd` into a directory.  You'll probably also want to append the date information to the output file, rather than always clobber it.  It also seems more likely that you'd copy the map files to the directory you just created.  So, you might write:

```
(mkdir flex01; cp *.map flex01; echo "Job 1: $(date)" >> out) &
(mkdir flex02; cp *.map flex02; echo "Job 2: $(date)" >> out) &
(mkdir flex03; cp *.map flex03; echo "Job 3: $(date)" >> out) &
(mkdir flex04; cp *.map flex04; echo "Job 4: $(date)" >> out) &

wait
```

This runs each sequence of commands as a separate background job, and then waits for them all to finish before proceeding.  You could look at using a loop for this task, too.

```
for n in $(seq 1 4)
do
    (mkdir flex0$n; cp *.map flex0$n; echo "Job $n: $(date)" >> out) &
done
```

You could also consider using `mkdir -p flex01` so you don't get error messages when trying to create a directory that already exists.  (Or you could test for errors and not copy if it exists, or test for existence before running `mkdir`, or clean it out before copying if it already exists, or ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can start each command and put it in the background by simply appending the `&` to your command line. I.e.,

```
date > out &
```

Since you are starting each command in a separate directory there won't be a problem with using the same name for the file catching your output.

**Update**:
Based on the additional information provided below in the comments, I believe your problem lies elsewhere and I would suggest you contact the site's helpdesk and/or look at some site-specific sample script files to help you set up your parallel jobs in the most effective way for the environment you are working in.

Comment: I tried this but it gives me error in the cluster computing server while running script (submit job )..but works while in command line

Comment: @hijo what is the error? I've used this many times in script files, so it may be something specific to your cluster setup. You should also consult your cluster's documentation, I am fairly certain they will have some commands to submit several jobs at once.

Comment: the work is partially run and premature ending ...I might need alternative looping procedure

Comment: @hijo That means the commands start .. so I would suspect there is a different problem. If you use this script file to just fire up one command, does that terminate successfully? The  supercomputer center I use provides sample scripts to user showing how to submit multiple jobs at once (and request various resources etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
seq 4 | parallel 'mkdir flex0{}; cp *.map flex0{}; echo "Job {}: $(date)" >> out'
```

It will run one process per CPU core.

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1